# Tableau: How do I copy row value for unique identifiers?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

How do I add calculated field for this?

I have table in tableau in following format (connected through redshift and every day 100000 rows are appended for the same ID1 and ID2, and sometimes new values for ID1 and ID2 are also added):

[image: ![enter image description here]

Value in `Date Field 1` could either be `Null` or `some date value` (which is appended every day). What I want is whenever for specific combination of `ID1` and `ID2`, `Date Field 1` is `not Null`, I want that value to be copied to other rows also as follows:

[image]

How do I do it?

Note: I got an answer for this question under SQL tag but it is with UPDATE table method: [SQL: Copy values for unique keys from one row to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813288/sql-copy-values-for-unique-keys-from-one-row-to-other/69813460?noredirect=1#69813460)

But I specifically need answer for tableau also to add calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated field using IF THEN statement as in the images below to look for a Match:

[image]

You can see the data reflects the new Match field as well:

[image]

Comment: This will work on small dataset, dataset I have, has millions of IDs.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you use the Custom SQL data source option so you can utilize the SQL solution you cited.  This will allow you to shift the heavy lifting to the source DBMS instead of trying to restructure such a huge dataset after bringing into Tableau Desktop.